# What " ' " does when written after any command in mac terminal?

Tags: command, iterm

I accidentally wrote `ls'` instead of `ls` for listing the files. And it shows the `>` option. later I checked with other commands like `cd'`, all providing `>`. What this command is for?

Example:

```
user:~$ ls'
>
>
>
user:~$ cd'
>
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started a string parameter after command. For example, you can pass multiline parameter this way. All typed data between '' will be treated as one parameter.